# DragEvent.relatedTarget returns null in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mouseevent, drag-event

If I try to check `e.relatedTarget` for `dragleave` event, in Safari (v14.1.2) it is always null.
You can see it here (add `console.log`) — https://jsfiddle.net/zfnj5rv4
In Chrome it works fine.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) says that Safari supports `MouseEvent.relatedTarget`.
[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent) says that `DragEvent` inherits properties from `MouseEvent` and `Event`.

Is it broken or never worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a longstanding bug in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66547